# Does a ticker tell a goroutine it is stopped through its ticker.C?

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

```
package main
import "fmt"
import "time"

func main() {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Millisecond * 500)
    go func() {
        for t := range ticker.C {
            fmt.Println("Tick at", t)
        }
        fmt.Println("ticker stopped")
    }()
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)
    ticker.Stop()
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)
}
```

I thought when I call ticker.Stop(), ticker.C should tell the goroutine that it is over, so the for loop should end, but it doesn't look like that, the string "ticker stopped" is never printed.

Comment: From the documentation: `Stop does not close the channel`

Answer (score 1):

As JimB pointed out, the documentation for the time.Ticker specifies that Stop() does not close the channel, `to prevent a read from the channel succeeding incorrectly.`  Your best bet is probably a quit channel.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"

func main() {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Millisecond * 500)
    quit := make(chan struct{})
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case t := <-ticker.C:
                fmt.Println("Tick at", t)
            case <-quit:
                fmt.Println("ticker stopped")
                return
            }
        }
    }()
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)
    ticker.Stop()
    close(quit)
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/xTKNkMtdIf

Comment: Sorry but I don't quite understand the reason why stop does not close the channel. I know you have explained it -- "to prevent a read from the channel succeeding incorrectly" , but it still confuse me.

Comment: @luckyyang This API design quirk has been brought up in the past, It looks to be an implementation problem. See https://codereview.appspot.com/5491059 for for more details.

Comment: So, let's say you have something somewhere that's just doing a `<-ticker.C` instead of doing it within a `for range` loop.  In such a case, closing the channel will trigger that receive just like an actual value being sent would (since receives from a closed channel instantly succeed).  So it doesn't close the channel so receivers can't get a close thinking it's a tick.

Comment: Very strange thing as I see. Ticking is a cyclic process so it would be logical to use `for I := range ticket.C` but not `t = <- ticker.C` and closing would be a good signal to break the loop.

Comment: I concur, but the latter use *is* sometimes used (arguably improperly), and the existing package was coded with that expectation.  Unfortunately, due to the [compatibility guarantee](https://golang.org/doc/go1compat), that behavior is almost definitely not going to change, at least until Go 2.0.